# Understanding $\epsilon-$net arguments for random matrix bounds

Tags: probability, matrices, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds, nets

I'm reading [this book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf#page97) to learn about $\epsilon$-net arguments for random matrix concentration bounds. In Section 4.2.2, a high probability upper bound is computed for the operator norm of matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, whose elements are independent, zero mean, and sub-Gaussian. I don't fully understand what the purpose of constructing an $\epsilon$-net is in this proof. Specifically, they prove that for any *fixed* $x \in S^{n-1}, y \in S^{m-1}$, we have
\begin{align}
P(\langle Ax, y\rangle \geq u) \leq 2 \exp(-cu^2/K^2),
\end{align}
where $K = \max \|A_{ij}\|_{\psi_2}$. We know that $\|A\|_2 = \max_{x \in S^{n-1}, y \in S^{m-1}} \langle Ax, y\rangle$. if we know that the above bound is true for *any* $x \in S^{n-1}, y \in S^{m-1}$, doesn't it imply that $P(\|A\|_2 \geq u) \leq 2 \exp(-cu^2/K^2)$? If so, why do we need the $\epsilon-$net argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\max_{x,y} P(\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u) \leq 2\exp(-cu^2/K^2)$, which does not allow you to infer $P(\max_{x,y} \langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u) \leq 2\exp(-cu^2/K^2)$ (note the difference between the two statements).

The event $\{\max_{x,y} \langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\}$ is a union of the events $\{\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\}$ over all $x,y$, i.e.
$$
\{\max_{x,y} \langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\} = \bigcup_{x,y} \{\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\},
$$
since $\max_{x,y} \langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u$ if and only if $\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u$ for some $x$, $y$. This means that the event $\{\max_{x,y} \langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\}$ in general has a larger probability that the events $\{\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u\}$ individually, and knowing something about the events $\{\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u \}$ individually will not directly give you anything about the union event.

When other approaches don't apply, one strategy of estimating such a union is to use countable subadditivity and upper bound it by a sum of the individual probabilities. However, for that you need the union to be countable, which is why people use $\varepsilon$-nets.

Comment: I am still confused about this. Could you please point out the mistake in the following argument? @spalein Let $$x^\ast, y^\ast = \arg \max_{x \in S^{n-1}, y \in S^{m-1}} \langle Ax, y \rangle.$$ Suppose we prove that for any $x \in S^{n-1}, y \in S^{m-1}$, we have $$P(\langle Ax, y \rangle \geq u) \leq 2\exp(-cu^2/K).$$ Because $x^\ast \in S^{n-1}, y^\ast \in S^{m-1}$, then $$P(\|A\|_2^2 \rangle \geq u) = P(\langle Ax^\ast, y^\ast \rangle \geq u) \leq 2\exp(-cu^2/K).$$

Comment: In these calculations, $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ are random variables; $A$ depends on the outcome, and $A$ influences which $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ are the maximizers. So in $P(\langle Ax^\ast,y^\ast\rangle \geq u)$, $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ are not fixed, and you cannot use that $P(\langle Ax,y\rangle \geq u)$ for fixed $x,y$.