# Difference between the random variable $f(x)\ge a$ for any $x$, and $\sup f(x)\ge a$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-functions

If our goal is to derive bound on $P(\sup_{x\in T} f(x)\geq a)$, where $T$ is a uncountably infinite subset $[0,1]^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n 1+w_i$ ($w_i$ is gaussian scalar), then we would need epsilon-net argument, given that for any $x$, the bound on $P(f(x)\geq a)\leq\exp(-a^2/2)$. However, I am confused on the difference between

(1) the random variable $P(f(x)\geq a)\leq p$, for any $x$

(2) $P(\sup_{x\in T} f(x)\geq a)=P(\forall x,f(x)\geq a)\leq p$.

$a$ is parameter.

Which one is stronger?

Update:

I think $P(\sup_{x\in T} f(x)\geq a)=P(\forall x,f(x)\geq a)$. But, if we want to derive bound on $P(\sup_{x\in T} f(x)\geq a)$, from any $x$, $P(f(x)\geq a)$, we need epsilon net argument, since union bound here does not work.

Am I correct?

Comment: @geetha290krm But this is very commonly addressed in high dimensional probability theory, for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635690/understanding-epsilon-net-arguments-for-random-matrix-bounds

Comment: More description of the problem is needed.  The sup is over what?  Is it $x$?  What is the set over which the sup is taken? (finite, countably infinite, uncountably infinite?) What is random? In what sense is the inequality $P[f(x)\geq a]\leq p$ a random variable?